# How to make `Joi` fill missing key/value pairs with some defaults?

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I didn't succeed in finding it on the web,
but I can't imagine this is not possible through `joi`.

Considering this very simple schema below...

```
Joi.object({
 field_1: Joi.string().required(),
 field_2: Joi.string().required(),
})
```

...and considering this provided object:
(note that `field_2` key and value are missing)

```
{field_1: "a string"}
```

I'd like `joi` to generate this complete object:

```
{field_1: "a string",
field_2: "a default value"}
```

How to do so?
Thanks

Comment: Use [`.default()`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#anydefaultvalue)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own validation function for a key.
If **value** is empty **return "any string"**.
For example:

```
const method = (value) => {
    if (value === '')
        return "default string"
    return value
}

Joi.object({
    field_1: Joi.string().custom(method, 'custom validation'),
    field_2: Joi.string().required(),
})
```

For more information: https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0

Comment: Thanks, but how do I retrieve/get back the complete object with both `field_1` and `field_2`?